# How can I get headers request using codeception from browser (headless or not)

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, codeception

This question could be repeated but I could not find any clear answer.

I am using Codecepting framework With crhome driver and selenium stand alone server.

I want to get the all the headers request for specific Url.

Pleas check the image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zu7Pn.png)

I have found one solution using phantomjs like shown in the code below:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {

  console.log('Request ' + JSON.stringify(request, undefined, 4));
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {

  console.log('Receive ' + JSON.stringify(response, undefined, 4));
};

page.open(Url);
```

However, I need solution when it used only Codeception or PHP without phantomjs

I found something called MobProxy:
https://github.com/edno/codeception-browsermob

But I try to install it but I am not sure if my step was right and it doesn't work .

Could please any one provide me with clear step to get the all the headers  request from browser and save them to file using Codeception or PHP ?

Answer (score 1):

Hi for who's interesting I found solution like this :

```
$I = new AcceptanceTester($scenario);

$I->amOnUrl(URL);
$w=$I->executeJS('return window.performance.getEntries();');

foreach ($w as $itme=>$value)
{
    echo($value['name']."\n";

}
```